# Skyrim FPS is about 5-10 FPS with Meminfo and 15-20 with ATT?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've installed the -Elys- Meminfo module and it shows me a lower framerate then with ATT. Who lies? Isn't this framerate too low to play the game? But I'm already level 39 and 100+ hours? Why is the -Elys- Meminfo don't work with ATT together? I must terminate ATT to read the Meminfo module. I think it's the ATT that makes the difference, unfortunatley it's hard to tell with this low quality box and this low framerate.

Comment: Uhm ... isn't it most important if the game feels playable to you? If you don't have a problem, then the framerate doesn't really matter, does it? What if I suddenly tell you that the game **must** have 60 FPS to be playable? Will your 100+ hours suddenly feel like agony to you?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: No, but I think it's important information because 10-20 FPS is really low and I don't have friends to test the game with higher settings.