# Skyrim Fraps Help

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, fraps

So I'm running Skyrim on high with AA of and AF on 4 with FXAA on. Everything else is on High. I was running it and and it feels like I'm getting around 40 to 50 FPS, but FRAPS says I'm getting 12... If I open the video in VLC FRAPS, it says I'm getting 40-50. I'm happy with my game performance now (I am used to play minecraft with 10 frames :D), but I would just like to know what's right.

Comment: Related: [Skyrim FPS is about 5-10 FPS with Meminfo and 15-20 with ATT?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43826/skyrim-fps-is-about-5-10-fps-with-meminfo-and-15-20-with-att). Skyrim seems to confuse FPS monitors…

Comment: Maybe try other soft like this http://mirillis.com/en/products/action.html (I'm not connected with this company)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not twitching about the place like your character has momentary seizures, or notices when time-stops because a Daedra got bored, and it's rather smooth, trust VLC. 12 FPS is twitchy like a MOFO, as you'd surely know if you're used to Minecrafting at 10.